# Is it possible to dynamically generate Android UI using a complex XML template file?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, templates

I am trying to dynamically generate a user interface by creating an XML template that will eventually be appended to a LinearLayout parent that is statically defined in the Activity XML. The LinearLayout parent that is statically defined is wrapped within a ScrollView.

In my sample code, it seems I am only able to transverse the parent LinearLayout of the template and not its children. I am also not getting any of its attributes, buttons, or images. I am using LayoutInflater to get the XMl and return it as a LinearLayout since that is the parent of my template file. Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_feed);
        Context context = getApplicationContext();

        final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        LinearLayout b = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.event, null);

        LinearLayout lLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_feed_parent);
        lLayout.addView(b);
    }
```

Here is my complex xml file I am trying to dynamically add to my parent LinearLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="325dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="100">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="17"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="15"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="100">

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="80"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="100">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/thumbs1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="343"
                android:textSize="18dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="12"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="33"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:text="Join"
        android:textSize="11dp" />

   </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I imported your code and I can display everything just fine. Can you share the xml from `R.layout.activity_feed`?

Comment: N.T. Thank you for your assistance, I have updated my question with more information. I don't see any Images loaded or buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I was able to load the template XML by using fragments. The following was added during onCreate() which fixed it...

```
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    EventActivity fragment = new EventActivity();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_feed_parent, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

It displays on my emulator. That being said, it doesn't display in the way you wanted.
Here are a couple of changes that you may try:

1. The SearchView and the ImageView next to it - they have weight property for width, but also have the width set to match the parent. Change it to `android:layout_width="0dp"`
2. The way you inflate the template causes some xml elements to be lost. When you inflate a view with the intention of adding it later to another view, you probably want to inflate in its parent "context":

`LinearLayout lLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_feed_parent);
 LinearLayout b = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.event, lLayout, false);`

or

`//this will return lLayout/parent, not the inflated view; template is automatically added to parent
(LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.event, lLayout, true);`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I will try it also and compare the performance.